# textbox data writes back to database, but textboxfor will not

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, html-helper

I'm picking up that it's a best practice to use the strongly-typed textboxfor helper method rather than simple textbox. I'm all for that. But as I made the switch in my project, the data stopped getting written back to the database. I'm having trouble figuring out why.

Here's my model.

```
public class MasterModel
{
    [Key]
    public int mandatoryKey { get; set; }
    public List<tblAddress> Address { get; set; }
    public List<tblPrimaryCaregiverdata> Primary { get; set; }
    public List<tblPhone> Phone { get; set; }
    public List<tblEmail> Email { get; set; }
    public List<tblRelatedCaregiver> Related { get; set; }
    public List<tblTrainingHistoryMain> TrainingHistory { get; set; }
    public List<tblInquiryReferralStatu> InquiryReferral { get; set; }
}
```

Then the controller

```
public ActionResult Create(MasterModel masterModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.tblPrimaryCaregiverdatas.Add(masterModel.Primary[0]);
            db.SaveChanges();

            int newCareGiverID = db.tblPrimaryCaregiverdatas.OrderByDescending(p => p.CareGiverID)
                .FirstOrDefault().CareGiverID;


            foreach (var ph in masterModel.Phone)
            {
                ph.CareGiverID = newCareGiverID;
                db.tblPhones.Add(ph);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Now, in the view (which invokes several partial views, one for each table in the master model), when I created the fields like this:

```
SelectList phonetypes = ViewBag.PhoneType;
<div>
    <label class="label-fixed-width">Phone:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("masterModel.Phone[0].phone", null, new { style = "width: 600px" })
    @Html.DropDownList("masterModel.Phone[0].PhoneType",phonetypes, null, new
    {
        @class = "form-control-inline dropdown",
        style = "width: 100px"
    })
```

...I was able to write data back into the database.  But when I switched over to textboxfor like this:

```
SelectList phonetypes = ViewBag.PhoneType;
<div>
    <label class="label-fixed-width">Phone:</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone[0].Phone, null, new { style = "width: 600px" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Phone[0].PhoneType, phonetypes,"--------", new
    {
        @class = "form-control-inline dropdown",
        style = "width: 100px"
    })
```

The Phone section of the MasterModel is empty when I post back. Can someone help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: try `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone[0].Phone, new { style = "width: 600px" })`

Comment: Alas, that doesn't work. I'm still getting null returned to the .Phone portion of the masterModel.

Comment: can you post your full view code

Answer (score 0):

When you post a model back to an ActionResult and return the same View, the values for the model objects are contained in the ModelState. The ModelState is what contains information about valid/invalid fields as well as the actual POSTed values. If you want to update a model value, you can do this:

```
 foreach (var ph in masterModel.Phone)
            {
               ModelState.Clear()//added here
                ph.CareGiverID = newCareGiverID;
                db.tblPhones.Add(ph);
            }
```

Comment: Clearing the model state change the fact that masterModel.Phone contains no data. The numbers entered into the text box on the view are simply not making it back to the controller.